# If I can add “if” after “before action” in redmine controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add permissions to my redmine plugin,and I set a method which will return three different value in three different situations.Different value means different permissions,but I get the syntaxs errors about my codes,I don
not know how to fix it.

```
class TextpollsController < ApplicationController
  before action:  if :the_value_of_the_role_id==6
                    :only => [:index,:vote,:setting]
                  elsif :the_value_of_the_role_id==7
                    :only => [:index]
                  elsif
                    deny_access
                  end

  def index
    @textpolls = Textpoll.all
  end
  ...

#the code of the_value_of_the_role_id
def the_value_of_the_role_id
    @user = User.current
    role_id=nil
     Textmember.each do|member|
       if member.user_id==@user.id
         role_id=member.role_id
       end
     end
    return role_id
  end
```

Comment: According to the compiler ,the error happened on ":only"

Comment: Don't drive yourself crazy. Use an authorization library: https://github.com/varvet/pundit

Answer (score 1):

This is the callback source code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#LC24

You can see that `only` and `except` are just `if` or `unless` statements.
So, you could do something like:

```
class TextpollsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :your_method, if: :should_be_called?

  def index
    @textpolls = Textpoll.all
  end

private

  def your_method
    # You can add your code here, it will be executed only if the role_id == 6
    # and if the action is :index, :vote or :setting
    # or if the role_id is == 7 and the action is :index
  end

  def should_be_called?
    # action_name is an attribute defined in rails to get the controller’s action name
    if (params[:role_id] == 6 && %w[index vote setting].include?(action_name)) ||
       (params[:role_id] == 7 && action_name == 'index')
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help,I fix my code as you said,the syntaxs error has gone,but I still can't realize permissions management.All users can do the action"index vote setting",It may have some error in my method“the value of role id”.In this plugin I set a model called textmember which contains two variable user_id and role_id.The user_id equal the User.current.id, if the role_id of textmember equal 6,they can do "index vote setting",if role_id equal 7,they can do“index”，else no permission getted.Please give me some advice about it,thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay, so this is not the good way to handle it. I mean, you can achieve it with this method, but it would not be clear and boring to maintain if you would have to do something like this for each controller, even with a concern. Please consider to use CanCanCan gem https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan. With this gem, you’ll have an Ability model, where you define all the abilities (tadam), then you will load it within your controllers. If the user is not allowed to access to an action, CanCan raise an exception then redirect the user where you want.